# How can I filter or query for cells in a table that fail its validation rule

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large table that contains a few data validation errors.
How can I filter or define a query to locate these errors?
I have thought of setting a conditional formatting rule but cannot figure out how to write the formula.
Does the red mark signifying the error have a method of describing it?
Cells in error may have a null entry or #N/A.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your spreadsheet, clearly showing the desired behavior?

Comment: Here is a very simple example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cD2ttkXfrllYVxIa26WHNhFEXyATQ408VR9yWJgWNeM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ISERROR()` function

```
=FILTER(B:B, ISERROR(A:A))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A12="",, REGEXMATCH(A2:A12&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A15:A25))))
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds interesting but I cannot replicate it in Google Sheets

Comment: Sample test worksheet now shared

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cD2ttkXfrllYVxIa26WHNhFEXyATQ408VR9yWJgWNeM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MervynThomas answer updated